# Angular 2+ how to get focus to modal inputs on opening the modal?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In a custom modal component that I have built, I want to get the input in the modal focused whenever the modal is opened

I tried two approaches:

1) Using `ViewChild` and `ElementRef`, then firing the focus(method), on modal open;

2) Using `document.getElementByID('test').focus()` method;

None of them worked

I tried testing another document property and it worked.

`document.getElementByID('test').innerHtml = 'test'`

but not the focus

simplified html for the modal:

```
<div [class.modal--open]="_open">
  <input #codeInput type="text" id='test'>
</div?
```

ts:

```
  @ViewChild('codeInput') codeInput: ElementRef
  @Input() set open(value: boolean) {
    this._open = value;
    if (value) {
     // here is where i need to get focus on the input
        document.getElementByID('test').focus() // did not work
        this.codeInput.nativeElement.focus() // did not work
    }
  }
```

Demo for testing https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ye3ag

Comment: You may just want to use `autofocus` on the html tag. Otherwise, you need to check whether the element is visible or not, since focus will trigger only on visible elements.

Comment: try enclosed in setTimeOut: `setTimeOut(()=>{this.codeInput.nativeElement.focus()})`

Comment: didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in modal class declaration, correct it and it will work

```
<div  [ngClass]="['modal', style]" [class.modal--open]="_open">
                    ^
<div  [ngClass]="modal" [class.modal--open]="_open">
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsszxc

Comment: the style class is a dynamic class that is delivered to the modal by an input it can not be removed because it breaks the modal functionality, however your answer has leaded me to the correct answer, and i can not resist to check mark your answer and give you points, thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

Just use autofocus in the input field

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" autofocus>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lsgbx9)

Comment: the autofocus is not working in my case, it has to be set problematically because it is only when the modal open, i have tried it though and does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some dynamic focusing then you can use the afterviewInit lifecycle hook where after viewInit you set the focus using renderer rather than native methods.

In you component

```
AfterViewinit() {    
this._renderer.setAttribute(elRef,'focus',true);    
}
```

Comment: I think this will set focus to the input while the modal in not displaying, because the modal shows on a button click, so i want to tie the focus whenever the modal opens that's why i put it in the set open()

Comment: Probably if your set open function is the one responsible for modal to show up.but i would recommend the use of renderer rather than the native methods.

Comment: here is what i did and didn't work also ```this._renderer.setAttribute(this.codeInput.nativeElement, 'focus', 'true');```

Comment: true should be boolean rather than a string

Comment: Try adding the atttribute autofocus as true rather than focus

Comment: Can you also try the AfterContentinit LifeCycle hook.This will be triggered after the view is initialized and also content is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, the focus is working it just needs some time to fire, I wrapped the `focus()` method with a `setTimeOut()` and it worked

```
    if (value) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.codeInput.nativeElement.focus()
      }, 1000)
    }
```

full solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ye3ag

Answer (score 0):

For those using - **ng-Bootstrap**

**Only** after calling the modal method  `open(...)`, you can take the element by id, and call method `focus()`

```
  public createCustomModal(modalDivElement: any, autoFocusElement?: string)
  {
    let ngbModalRef = this.ngbModalService.open(modalDivElement);
    if (autoFocusElement)
    {
      document.getElementById(autoFocusElement).focus();
    }

    return ngbModalRef;
  }
```